# PyCharm - can't type in the console

Tags: python, console, pycharm

I'm a beginner so I suppose this might be a silly question to you guys but I've tried everything and I'm feeling desperate. In PyCharm, I'm trying to `input("Enter string:")` and the `"Enter string"` statement shows up in the console, but I can't type in anything. Would you have any idea what this might be ?

I didn't change any of the detailed configurations

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Also, check what boxes are checked in `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console`

Answer (score 0):

Silly thought, but are you clicking in the window to put your cursor where you need to type?

It should be there by default when you run your application in PyCharm, but I've occasionally been clicking elsewhere.

[image]